latest kernels issue, wont lauch
i'm not sure exactly which version, but I think my graphics card has a problem with kernel 6.8 and later. When i want to install arch linux, i should add "nomodeset" to grub so i can install arch. But when i try to install latest kernel, it wont boot until i add "nomodeset" to grub but as you know it sucks for graphics. when i install lts kernel, there is no problem but i think it will be problem for me soon and i want to install latest kernel. i tried fedora 40 but even if i edit grub "nomodeset" i didnt work. i have amd ryzen 5 1600 af cpu and Amd rx 470 gpu. How can i fix? im new linux user btw but im forcing to learn

https://community.frame.work/t/resolved-linux-wont-start-on-amd-without-nomodeset/42220/25 same problem.. The problem was solved with a new motherboard. Is there no other solution? :(

You linked to a very specific hardware discussion, do you have a Framework laptop, or do you have unrelated hardware?
